# angular-ui-router.d.ts cannot add the item

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, angular-ui-router, azure-devops

Visual Studio keeps pops up this error when opening my solution (which includes a project that has that file). How I can solve this error?

[image]

Comment: What's the result if you remove that file from solution and source control (check in changes), then add it again?

Comment: Do you solve that issue?

Comment: @starain: I've removed from the source code (I know that its not quite recommended but for me was one of the options). Since I wasn't using the type script at all in was only within the source folders from bower repo

Comment: Since your issue has been solved, you can post a answer and mark it after 24 hours.

Comment: @starain: I haven't considered my solution like a good approach, but will add an answer anyway :)

Comment: You can mark it after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that its not quite recommended but for me was one of the options to remove the files from TFS (version folder: local & remote).

Since I wasn't using the type script at all in was only within the source folders from bower repo (angular-ui-router).